# Scope relying on association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following associations:

```
Order belongs_to OrderStatus
```

I want to have an Order scope that would give me all the `Orders` which `OrderStatus` is `'ready'`.

`OrderStatus` has an attribute called `name`, and that is where the `'ready'` is.

So, I have tried this:

```
scope :ready, -> { where('order_status.name = ?', 'ready') }
```

But it is not working as expected. `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "order_status"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join the associated (order_status) model:

```
scope :ready, -> { joins(:order_status).where('order_statuses.name' => 'ready') }
```